# CSS "Checkbox hack" z-index not working

Tags: html, css, user-interface, z-index

I'm using the css "checkbox hack" so that when someone clicks on a label, a form pops up. The form element is using a `:before` pseudo element to create a transparent background, but for some reason I can't get the z-index to take effect on the form so that the background appears behind the form. If you go past a certain difference in z-indexes, the inputs of the form appear on top of the `:before` pseudo element, but not the background or button colors, etc.

I've already tried wrapping the form in a `div`, which I was able to get to work. However, w3c validator doesn't like a `div` as a child of a label element. Trying to figure it out using a pseudo element, since I've seen it work before.

The form position attribute is set to `absolute` and the pseudo element to `fixed`. I read that it might have something to do with it, but I changed them all & it still doesn't have the desired effect. There are no other z-indexes edited in the rest of the css file.

```css
section input:checked + .modal_form:before {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  z-index: 0;
}
section input:checked + .modal_form {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 108px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -290px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.modal_form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 580px;
  padding: 36px 40px 40px 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<label for="modal_toggle">
  <span class="todo">Item 1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="modal_toggle" />
  <form action="#" method="post" class="modal_form">
    <fieldset>
      <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
          </dt>
        <dd>
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Todo Name" />
        </dd>
      </dl>

      <dl>
        <dt>
            <label>Due Date</label>
          </dt>
        <dd>
          <input type="number" name="day" min="1" max="31" placeholder="Day" />
          <!--
            --><span class="separator">/</span>
        </dd>
        <!--
          -->
        <dd>
          <input type="number" name="month" min="1" max="12" placeholder="Month" />
          <!--
            --><span class="separator">/</span>
        </dd>
        <!--
          -->
        <dd>
          <input type="number" name="year" min="2017" max="2099" placeholder="Year" />
        </dd>
      </dl>

      <dl>
        <dt class="top_align">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
          </dt>
        <dd class="description">
          <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="field_align">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      <input type="submit" value="Mark As Complete" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing the position to relative

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: If you want answers you need to include your code in the question.

Comment: @seemly thank you. @araymer I tried changing the display properties. @Paulie_D, thanks for the feedback. It seems like the `div` is necessary in order to use the `:before` element.

Answer (score -1):

Using a negative z-index on an element will place it behind it's parent.

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
}

form:after {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  background: red;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>asdf</label>
</form>
```